# Vectorization of min distance in kernel

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, lookup, bsxfun

I have an Nx2 array `K1` with the location of N keypoints and a 3 dimensional WxHx3 array `Kart1(width,height,coordinates)` that maps coordinates to every pixel of an image. For every keypoint in `K1` I want to read the location of the pixel in `Kart1` and evaluate the coordinates (search for the min/max or calculate the mean) in a 3x3 kernel around it and assign a value to the current pixel in `KPCoor1`.

My current approach looks like this:

```
for ii=1:length(K1(:,1)) %for every keypoint in K1

    MinDist=sqrt(sum(Kart1(K1(ii,2)-1,K1(ii,1)-1,:).^2)); %Calculate distance
    xShift=0;
    yShift=0;
    for kk=-1:1 %for every pixel in a 3x3 kernel...
        for ll=-1:1

            Distance=sqrt(sum(Kart1(K1(ii,2)+kk,K1(ii,1)+ll,:).^2));

            if Distance<MinDist   %... if the current distance is smaller than MinDist
                MinDist=Distance; %... update MinDist...
                xShift=kk; %... and take the kernel coordinate of the pixel
                yShift=ll;
            end

        end
    end

    KP1Coor(ii,:)=Kart1(K1(ii,2)+xShift,K1(ii,1)+yShift,:); %assign the coordinates of the pixel with the minimal distance in kernel.

end
```

and it runs, but is ugly and I doubt it's doing what I want to do. I am a bit confused by the "multidimensionality" of the matter,  don't know many functions to evaluate kernels, and can't think of a way to use vectorization functions like `bsxfun()` or logic operations (means I'm stuck and my brain is dry :/)

Any suggestions on how to eliminate those loops/correct the code?

Comment: I think you need `xShift=-1` and `yShift=-1` inside the first nested loop, don't you think? Also, do you need `MinDist` as the output?

Comment: In this case I am more interested in 'where' the minimal distance is, and I read that from the shifts in x and y. That's what I use them for. PS: I solved the problem in a more elegant way altogether, stll thanks for commenting on an old question!

Comment: Well I still went ahead with my own solution based on `bsxfun`! You said you already have implemented an efficient version of it and I was thinking that I won't mind a little `showdown of benchmarks` against the one presented here, if you would like too :) If you do, maybe you can edit your question with it or make your own solution here, though I would think the latter one would be nice.

Comment: I meant I don't need to look for that any longer, but rest assured that your answer would have won the showdown by far! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vectorized approach:** After diving into the vectorized implementation, it looked like a very interesting `look-up problem`, so if you are still interested in vectorized techniques to get the job done, here's an approach with [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
%// Scalars to replace their repeated usages in the code
[W,H,NC]= size(Kart1);
d3a = 1:NC;

%// Indices for Kart1 at the first level of the nested loops
BI = bsxfun(@plus,K1(:,2)+(K1(:,1)-1)*W,(d3a-1)*W*H);

%// Indices for Kart1 in 3x3 kernel around the indices obtained at first level
BIW3 = bsxfun(@plus,[-1 0 1]',[-W 0 W]); %//'
%// Linear indices for the minimum value of Kart1 in the 3x3 neighborhood 
[~,MI3] = min(sqrt(sum(Kart1(bsxfun(@plus,...
    BI,permute(BIW3(:),[3 2 1]))).^2,2)),[],3);
%// X-Y indices
[xShift1,yShift1] = ind2sub([3 3],MI3);

%// Get Kart1 values corresponding to the indices for the minimum values
KP1Coor = Kart1(bsxfun(@plus,...
    K1(:,2)+xShift1-2 +(K1(:,1)+yShift1-2-1)*W,(d3a-1)*W*H));
```

**Benchmarking**

I was able to test it out with GPU too using `gpuArray` from Parallel Computing Toolbox and then run some benchmarks with `W = 1000`, `H = 1000` and used `N` as the datasize varying it with `[1000 2000 5000 10000 20000]`. The results seem crazy enough, though not unreliable as approved benchmarking methods were used from [`Measure and Improve GPU Performance`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html). Here is the benchmark plot for original and CPU and GPU vectorized codes -

[image]

It looked appropriate to then benchmark only the vectorized codes and for even larger datasizes, whose plot is shown next -

[image]

**Conclusions:** The problem basically looks like a look-up problem, where `Kart1` is the data and `K1` is the array of indices to look-up for. The vectorized solution presented here is basically a brute-force approach and the benchmark results clearly favor this for performance. But, it would be interesting to see if any non-brute-force approach that might be even loop-based, but leverages this looking up efficiently could perform better.

Comment: Thank you for such an amazing answer and for coming back to an old question! Even though outside a current problem, I learn a lot and get new ideas from your "works"!